# .NET UpdatePanel and FaceBook / Twitter Buttons

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, twitter, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel which has a gridview inside it. On each of the gridviewrows, within the gridview, I have a Twitter and FaceBook button.

The gridview renders fine with the buttons on page load, however, once a partial postback is done on the updatepanel the Twitter and FaceBook buttons do not render.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
<!-- search controls.... -->
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnSearch" ImageUrl="~/img/button-search.gif" runat="server" />

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableModelValidation="True"
                BorderStyle="None" Font-Size="Small" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="True" ShowFooter="True"
                Width="100%" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
                <RowStyle CssClass="row1" />
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="row2" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            ...
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Literal ID="ltlTwitter" runat="server" Text='<%# GetTwitterURL(Eval("ID"), Eval("SomeText")) %>'></asp:Literal>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Literal ID="ltlFacebook" runat="server" Text='<%# GetFacebookURL(Eval("ID")) %>'></asp:Literal>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False" />
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <strong>There are no offers for this search criteria.</strong>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearch" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Relevant C#:

```
public static string GetTwitterURL(object ID, object text)
{
    ...           
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<div>");
    sb.Append("<a href=\"http://twitter.com/share\" " +
        "class=\"twitter-share-button\" ");
    sb.AppendFormat("data-url=\"{0}?ID={1}\" ", obj.Property, oID.ToString());
    sb.Append("data-via=\"xxx\" ");
    sb.AppendFormat("data-text=\"{0}\"", xxx);
    sb.Append("data-count=\"none\">Tweet</a>");

    sb.Append("</div>");

    return sb.ToString();

}

public static string GetFacebookURL(object OfferID)
{
    ...

    return string.Format("<fb:like href=\"{0}?ID={1}\" " +
        "send=\"false\" layout=\"button_count\" show_faces=\"false\" " +
        "action=\"like\" font=\"tahoma\"></fb:like>", obj.Property, someInt);
}
```

Also, the page in question is a child page of a master page.

**Here is the additional code-behind**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        this.BindOffersGrid(true);
    }
}

public List<Offer> CurrentOffersDataSet
{
    get
    {
        object o = ViewState["CurrentOfferDataSet"];
        return (o == null ? new List<Offer>() : (List<Offer>)o);
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["CurrentOfferDataSet"] = value;
    }
}

protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataSource = this.CurrentOffersDataSet;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

private void BindOffersGrid(bool ApplyRandomSort)
{
    List<Offer> lstOffers = Offers.GetAllBySearchCriteria(
        Convert.ToInt32(ddlOfferCounty.SelectedValue), 
        Convert.ToInt32(ddlOfferTypes.SelectedValue),
        Convert.ToDateTime(ddlOfferDate.SelectedValue), -1, true);

    ...
    //Some filtering of the dataset with Linq
    ...

    GridView1.DataSourceID = string.Empty;
    this.CurrentOffersDataSet = lstFilteredOffers.
        OrderByDescending(a => a.IsExclusive).
        ThenBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()).
        ToList();
    GridView1.DataSource = this.CurrentOffersDataSet;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting them in code-behind on item bound event? It could be that the inline script calls aren't fully compatible, but I'm unsure as I tend to stay away from use of such as a matter of course.

Comment: @Seany84: It should be noted that you don't really need a `StringBuilder` for the concatenation you are doing in the `GetTwitterURL` method; you can get by with calling `string.Format` and breaking up the string into multiple concatenations on multiple lines.  The compiler will concatenate what it can at compile-time and then the concatenation operations will call `string.Concat` which pre-determines the size of the return value and then copies all the items over into the string that is returned.

Comment: @casperOne
Thanks for the tips.

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment
Are you suggesting I call the GetTwitter() / GetFB() on RowDatabound event of the grid?

Comment: @Mr. Disappointment
I have tried calling the GetFB() and GetTwitter() and setting the text of the Literals on the RowDataBound event but it's the exact same problem.

Comment: @Seany84 The problem doesn't seem to be with the field binding specifically so changing it to use the `RowDataBinding` (which is bad, you should use the `Literal` controls `OnDataBinding` method) shouldn't affect it.  Can you answer the rest of my questions?  What is causing the refresh trigger, and is anything else showing up in the grid other than the buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I added the following code at the very end of my child page and now the Twitter and FaceBook like button are appearing after partial postbacks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
        prm.add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);

        var _panels, _count;

        function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
            if (_panels != undefined && _panels.length > 0) {
                for (i = 0; i < _panels.length; i++)
                    _panels[i].dispose();
            }

            var panels = args.get_panelsUpdated();

            if (panels.length > 0) {

                updateFbLike();
            }
        }

        function updateFbLike() {
            $.getScript("http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js");
            FB.XFBML.parse();
        }


    </script>
```